# TD Inheriting TABLE width

Tags: html, css, html-table, width

The issue I'm facing is that a TD in my table is inheriting the table's width despite having it's own width explicitly set.

The code is as follows:

```
    <div class="widget widget-new-products">
    <div class="widget-products">
        <table cellspacing="0" width="640px" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center">
               <tr>
                    <td>
                            <img src="header.gif" alt="New Releases">
                    </td>
            </tr>

                       <tr style="font-size: 0;">

                                <td width="30px"><img width="30px" height="95px" src="leftsep.gif" alt="" ></td>

                                <td width="85px">
                                   <a href="" title="" class="product-image"><img src="product1.jpg" width="85" height="85" alt="image" ></a>
                                </td>

                                <td width="100px">
                                    <a style="font-family:sans-serif; font-size:13px; line-height:14px; color:#444; font-weight:bold;" title="" href="">item 1</a>
                                </td>

                                <td width="100px" align="right">
                                    <p style="font-family:sans-serif; font-size:22px; line-height:24px; font-weight:bold; color:#e05371; margin:0 0 5px 0;">£30.00</p>
                                    <a href=""><img src="view-product.jpg" height="30px" width="111px" alt="View Product"></a>
                                </td>

                               <td width="10px">
                               </td>

                                <td width="85px">
                                   <a href="" title="" class="product-image"><img src="product2.jpg" width="85" height="85" alt="" ></a>
                                </td>

                                <td width="100px">
                                    <a style="font-family:sans-serif; font-size:13px; line-height:14px; color:#444; font-weight:bold;" title="" href="">item 2</a>
                                </td>

                                <td width="100px" align="right">
                                    <p style="font-family:sans-serif; font-size:22px; line-height:24px; font-weight:bold; color:#e05371; margin:0 0 5px 0;">£10.00</p>
                                    <a href=""><img src="view-product.jpg" height="30px" width="111px" alt="View Product"></a>
                                </td>

                                <td width="30px"><img width="30px" height="95px" src="rightsep.gif" alt=""></td>

                        </tr>  

                <tr>
                    <td>
                            <img src="footer.gif" alt="">
                    </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Specifically, the TD being affected is the first in the table:

```
<td width="30px"><img width="30px" height="95px" src="leftsep.gif" alt="" ></td>
```

Which is inheriting the table width of **640px** instead of the **30px** it should be.

It seems regardless of what I change, the issue is still there.. I've tested both locally and in JSFiddle.

I'm by no means experienced in HTML so I'm not sure what the problem is.

**Updated Code**

```
        <div class="widget widget-new-products">
    <div class="widget-products">
        <table cellspacing="0" width="640px" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" style="border-spacing: 0;">
               <tr>
                    <td colspan="8">
                            <img src="http://crazybeatweb1.cms.iwebcloud.co.uk/media/newsletter/new-releases.gif" alt="New Releases">
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>

                        <td width="30"><img width="30px" height="95px" src="http://crazybeatweb1.cms.iwebcloud.co.uk/media/newsletter/new-releases-left.gif" alt="" ></td>

                        <td width="85">
                           <a href="" title="" class="product-image"><img src="http://crazybeatweb1.cms.iwebcloud.co.uk/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/85x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/1/_/1.jpg_14603.jpg" width="85" height="85" alt="image" ></a>
                        </td>

                        <td width="100">
                            <a style="font-family:sans-serif; font-size:13px; line-height:14px; color:#444; font-weight:bold;" title="" href="">Clydie King - Direct Me - Inc Never Like This Before</a>
                        </td>

                        <td width="111" align="right">
                            <p style="font-family:sans-serif; font-size:22px; line-height:24px; font-weight:bold; color:#e05371; margin:0 0 5px 0;">£30.00</p>
                            <a href=""><img src="http://crazybeatweb1.cms.iwebcloud.co.uk/media/newsletter/view-product.jpg" height="30px" width="111px" alt="View Product"></a>
                        </td>

                        <td width="85">
                           <a href="" title="" class="product-image"><img src="http://crazybeatweb1.cms.iwebcloud.co.uk/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/85x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/4/_/4.jpg_14418.jpg" width="85" height="85" alt="" ></a>
                        </td>

                        <td width="100">
                            <a style="font-family:sans-serif; font-size:13px; line-height:14px; color:#444; font-weight:bold;" title="" href="">T.M.V.S. - Don't Be Shy</a>
                        </td>

                        <td width="111" align="right">
                            <p style="font-family:sans-serif; font-size:22px; line-height:24px; font-weight:bold; color:#e05371; margin:0 0 5px 0;">£10.00</p>
                            <a href=""><img src="http://crazybeatweb1.cms.iwebcloud.co.uk/media/newsletter/view-product.jpg" height="30px" width="111px" alt="View Product"></a>
                        </td>

                        <td width="30">
                            <img width="30px" height="95px" src="http://crazybeatweb1.cms.iwebcloud.co.uk/media/newsletter/new-releases-right.gif" alt="">
                        </td>

                </tr>  

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="8">
                        <img src="http://crazybeatweb1.cms.iwebcloud.co.uk/media/newsletter/new-releases-bottom.gif" alt="">
                    </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

I now have a gap above and below the middle row which I can't get rid of.

Comment: You should be using CSS for styling your table.

Comment: I would recommend to use a css file instead. If you still want to define with on table tags, don't use px, like <table width="100">, or inside inline style (with px): style="width:100px" ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every row in a table must have the same number of cells. If you want to use less cells in a row you must explicitly set the `colspan` attribute to match:

```
   <tr>
        <td colspan="9"> <!-- set this to the maximum number of cells there will be in a row -->
            <img src="header.gif" alt="New Releases">
       </td>
    </tr>
```

---

You can mix and match the `colspan`:

```
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">
            <img src="header.gif" alt="New Releases">
        </td>
        <td colspan="4"> 
            <img src="header.gif" alt="New Releases">
        </td>
    </tr>
```

but the total must always match the maximum number of cells used in the table.

This process must be repeated for every row in the table.

Comment: This works, thanks. However I now have a gap above and below the middle row (I've updated with the new code)

Comment: How many cells in your middle row? You had 9 in the first block of code but only 8 in the your second block making `colspan="9"` wrong

Comment: Sorry I made an edit and forgot to change that, it is indeed 8 but the error persists with colspan changes. Seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/wY4VH/

Comment: I don't see a gap http://jsfiddle.net/wY4VH/1/ are you sure its not part of the image? I cant tell because your server is password protected

Comment: ... try setting your images to `display:block`

Comment: Sorry! I forgot I had it set to protected, setting the images to `display:block` fixed the problem, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be:

```
<td width="200">
```

or

```
<td style="width: 200px">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a table with 3 rows, but different numbers of cells.
If you want a cell to span the whole table, like the header and footer do, you need to specifiy a rowspan on them like this:

```
<tr>
    <td rowspan="9"><img src="header.gif" alt="New Releases"></td>
</tr>
```

In this case a 9, because your middle row has 9 cells.
Otherwise the browser will render the table wrong.